# If Statement using List of Variables in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write an if statement that checks the current excel tab versus a list (either stored on another tab, manually entered in a list in vba, or other) and this is in a loop. It all works fine if I manually type in one item off the list in VBA but I cant figure out a way to have it reference the entire list.

I have tried cases, referencing a range, manually putting the list in the direct VBA code.

The desired result is having the "ABC" being a list of 20-40 different items. I'm hoping to avoid a super long or statement. For efficiency I was hoping to just put = some range so that I dont have to manually update VBA everytime the data changes.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets 'This statement starts the loop
    If ws.Name = "ABC" Then
```

Comment: `if isnumeric(application.match(ws.name,range("A1:A20"),0)) then` ?

Comment: It may be the case that a description of what you want to do with this selected data may result in a more efficient method of accomplishing your end goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the code below will fit your needs (see code notes for some explanations):

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim SheetNamesArr As Variant

' read the sheet names array from a range in one of your sheets
SheetNamesArr = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A10") ' <-- you can modify the range to suit your needs

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets 'This statement starts the loop
    ' use Match to find if shee't sname is found within an array
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(ws.Name, SheetNamesArr, 0)) Then
        ' do something if sheet's name is found

    Else
        ' do something else >> raise an error msg

    End If

Next ws
```